# Have version on the css file .css?v=1.0.0.3

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952678/css-query-string)

How is possible to have the versions on the css file or javascript file??

For example lite this
ui-selectmenu.css?v=1.0.0.3

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but that _looks like_ what some people do to prevent browsers from not loading a cached file when something changes in that file. For example, if a designer changes the CSS, they can update the HTML to request a later version of the CSS file (for example, 1.0.0.4). The browser would request the latest version of the file since the file it is requesting appears to have changed.

Comment: This question gets asked a different way every day.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a version stamp to a URL for a static resource is used for cache busting. It forces browsers to issue a request for the resource (since the URL is different) rather than just use the resource in the browser cache. This prevents the rendering of an updated HTML page with stale CSS/js/images/etc.

Comment: is this the only reason why they are putting version on the css file?

Comment: @Troj read the file and if you see any tags like `<?php` then there may be other reasons. That's not very likely...

Comment: Typically this is the only reason. Easy way to test is request the CSS file with different ?v= values and see what comes back. You should get the same result back every time unless they're running some code on the server side that interprets the version and surfaces a different CSS file. Personally I've never seen this done in the wild.